# GetProcessDEPPolicy error 87

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015

When I try to check if some process is using data execution protection (DEP) I get error 87 (INVALID_PARAMETER). I checked my code and it seems to be okay but unfortunately I still have the same error.

Code:

```
BOOL var = true;
DWORD dwPolicy;

HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, false, 3624);
if (hProc == NULL) {
    cout << "Can't open Process because of the error " << GetLastError() << endl;
}

if (GetProcessDEPPolicy(hProc, &dwPolicy, 0) != FALSE) {
    if (dwPolicy == PROCESS_DEP_ENABLE) {
        cout << "For try.exe process data execution prevention is enabled" << endl;

    }
    else if (dwPolicy == NULL) {
        cout << "For try.exe process data execution prevention is disabled" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Data is thrunked and we can't change DEP value in future" << endl;
    }
}
else {
    cout << "There was an error with discovering DEP in try.exe process because of "<<GetLastError() << endl;
}
```

After compiling and execution I get:

```
There was an error with discovering DEP in try.exe process because of 87
```

Comment: On a side note, you should not be calling `GetProcessDEPPolicy()` if `OpenProcess()` fails. And don't forget to call `CloseHandle()` on the opened `HANDLE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the documentation, the function [`GetProcessDEPPolicy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb736297.aspx) is defined:

```
BOOL WINAPI GetProcessDEPPolicy(
  _In_  HANDLE  hProcess,
  _Out_ LPDWORD lpFlags,
  _Out_ PBOOL   lpPermanent
);
```

Notice that the last argument is an out parameter and it's not optional, but you're passing 0 aka `NULL`. The call should be:

```
BOOL permanent = FALSE;
if (GetProcessDEPPolicy(hProc, &dwPolicy, &permanent) != FALSE) {
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped